# What does '--' mean or do in a lookup in Informatica Developer mapping?

Tags: lookup, informatica-powercenter

In lookups in Informatica Devloper mappings on our enviroment, I reguarly see '--' in the Lookup sql overrides. It is at the end of the script. Normally I 'd interpret a '--' as 'comment out' of sql.

Though a colleagues says it has to do with the fact that some kind of ordering will be applied. But I can't find more info about it on the net.

Can anyone tell me what '--' at the end of a Lookup sql override mean or do in a lookup? Or where to find more info about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct: Informatica by default adds the ORDER BY statement to the SQL Override. The '--' at the end of the statement disables it. BUT:

- Informatica does that on purpose. It's there to make the cache building faster - cache is sorted to improve the cache reads. It should be reflecting the order of ports mentioned on `Condition` tab of `Lookup Transformation`
- If the ORDER BY is disabled, you will probably see the following message in session log indicating a possible performance degradation:

  `Message: Warning: Unsorted input found when building the cache for the Lookup transformation [lkp_name]. ...`

In general this should be avoided. (Well - the SQL overrides should be avoided at all. For many reasons. But that's a different story.) However in some special cases this might be needed and be fully justified.

Example:

The `Condition` is defined to do the matching on ports A, B, C - but the rows are not unique and we need to get the latest row using `updatedOn`. In this case we might use a
`Use First Value` for `Lookup policy on multiple match` property. And to ensure that the most recently updated row will be first we include our own `ORDER BY A, B, C, updatedOn desc --` clause. This will make sure that data is sorted by the condition columns as we need, and the most recent row will come first. And `--` needs to be there to prevent the second `ORDER BY` clause that Informatica will add anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I heard and can confirm that the lookup automatically adds an order by to a lookup when the workflow is run.

When adding '--' add the end of the sql override, NO addiditional ordering is added.